# Record the user’s route during a workout on AppleWatch

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I implemented running recording based on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/running_workout_sessions the problem is that I don't see location and map in Fitness app. Map section isn't visible at all.

What should I add to save route ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/creating_a_workout_route

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for pointing it. I saw the article. The problem is that it is for iPhone. For Apple Watch I use HKLiveWorkoutDataSource https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkliveworkoutdatasource and there is no way to add location data

Comment: What sort of workout are you building?  Is it an outdoor activity?  The documentation suggests that an outdoor cycle will collect location data while an indoor cycle won't, but this may just be used for distance.  When you call `finishWorkout` you receive a `HKWorkout` via the closure. You could pass this to your route builder to associate the route with the workout.

Comment: It was really helpful ! I missed that part that I can associate the route with the workout, thank you! It works now

Comment: @Paulw11 answer is the correct strategy.